# Can't copy project folder on Windows 10 to docker container

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm learning about Docker and trying to up a container using php, apache and Lumen Framework. When I execute the command to build the container, returns success.

The problem is when I open the http://localhost:8080 and the page show me 403 - forbidden on apache. I access the container by ssh and I look on the folder /srv/app/ and there's no files. I think that the problem is the mapping of the folder root on the host machine Windows.

I'm using Windows 10;

Anyone can help me?

***My DockerFile***

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

LABEL maintainer="rIckSanchez"

COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

COPY . /srv/app

COPY docker/apache/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf
```

***My docker-compose file***

```
version: '3'

services:

  phpinfo:

    build: .

    ports:

    - "8080:80"
```

Comment: You've posted links to images instead of appropriate code snippets, we'd have to rewrite your code by hand and hope that the links to your images won't expire over time. Please edit your question.

Comment: I changed my question, tks!

Comment: Now you should format the code properly ;) select the code and click "code" button in the editor.

Comment: Solved! I reinstalled the Docker for Windowns and after I executed the command, he request to share disk C:/ I get success!